# After click append child with input field like tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create organization structure with left child and right child. 
just like this demo
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-An-Editable-Organization-Chart-with-jQuery-orgChart-Plugin/

But I want to save data from here with input field.
I want to create left child and right child for each after click. now all displaying one after one in bottom and only remove button. I want add button also for creating child for each input form.
Here I used like this

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
  });

  $('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}
h2 {
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
h2 a {
  color: #224f99;
}
a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #802727;
}
p {
  padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
input {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -web-kit-border-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
    <label for="p_scnts">
      <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/re8e2yov/) 
 I want to create tree structure same  as that plugin with input form. but failed to do that. my snippet is not working in question so I placed jsfiddle link.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: `.live` is deprecated. Use `.on` method instead.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi I want to create tree structure same  as that plugin with input form. but failed to do that. my snippet is not working in question so I placed jsfiddle link.

Comment: Build a tree first and then modify your question so that it fits the problem ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various errors in your code mainly the id's should be unique. And use **[`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead of **[`live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/)** since it's depreciated in new versions. You can do something like this with use of table  , it's a simple demo you need to update it

```js
// bind click event handler
$("#main").on('click', '.add', function() {
  //getting parent td
  var $td = $(this).parent();
  // creating child element
  var $td1 = $('<td>', {
    html: '<input  />      <button class="add">+</button>      <button class="remove">-</button>'
  });
  // getting child table if there is
  var $tbl = $td.children('table')
    // checking child exist or not , if yes then append child to it
  if ($tbl.length)
    $tbl.find('tr').eq(0).append($td1);
  // else create new table and update
  else
    $td.append($('<table>', {
      html: $('<tr>', {
        html: $td1
      })
    }))
    // bind remove handler
}).on('click', '.remove', function() {
  // remove the parent td
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 20px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" style="width:100%;text-align:center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
      <button class="add">
        +
      </button>
      <button class="remove">
        -
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This may do the job but I admit there is some bugs, But I think it still worthy to look .. I made it with the help of Bootstrap Grid System.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parent-col col-md-12">
      <input type="text" />
      <BR />
      <a class='sibling'>Add Sibling</a>
      or
      <a class='child'>Add Child</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.child').click(function(){
    var r = $(this).closest('div.row').clone(true, true);
  r.find('.parent-col').not(':eq(0)').remove();
  var c = $(this).closest('.parent-col');
  var n = c.append( r );
});

$('.sibling').click(function(){

  var thisC = $(this).closest('.parent-col');
  var n = thisC.clone(true, true);
  thisC.after(n);
    var c = $(this).closest('div.row');
    var len = $('div.parent-col', c).length;
  var newClass = Math.ceil(12/len);
  c.find('.parent-col').attr('class', 'parent-col col-md-'+newClass);

});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/re8e2yov/6/)

Test it in full width view to easily notice the tree structure.

Comment: Thanks. Much better answer. Ok I will try this with my css and then I will accept your answer. It will take some time for me.

Comment: oh I get more perfect answer. +1 for you

Comment: I see. I never thought that is what you want. Thanks for +1 and appreciation but he understand you more. I'm still glad because you got what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

The elements are being added dynamically to the page, so the events are not bound to the elements that are added.

Check this Code. It will work.

```js
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
      $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
       i++;
                return false;
        });
  $(document).on("click", '#remScnt', function(e) {
         if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).closest('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
               return false;
     });
   });
```

```css
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I need child structure like tree. and here only remove option for appended input field. I need both add and remove with tree structure.